# On ATtiny84, why does delay() stop working properly when RadioHead ASK is used?

Tags: microcontroller, attiny

Moved to: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/90758/on-attiny84-why-does-delay-stop-working-properly-when-radiohead-ask-is-used

When I call the `delay()` function on the ATtiny84 micro, it delays for the expected time, until I call the `init()` function on an `RH_ASK` object. After this, the micro seems to freeze.

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
RH_ASK driver();

void setup() {
    delay(100); // works ok
    driver.init();
    delay(100); // freezes a long time (or maybe forever?)
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it should be moved to the Arduino community: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/90758/on-attiny84-why-does-delay-stop-working-properly-when-radiohead-ask-is-used

Comment: Nick - Hi, Thanks for adding your solution. (a) Re: "I think it should be moved to the [Arduino community](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/90758)". Since you're writing firmware, the question is not off-topic here, although I agree it's a better fit over there. The only way to migrate questions to an SE site which is not on the short list available in the Close option, is to flag the question for moderator attention. If this situation happens again, please do that. (b) Reposting the same question to multiple SE sites is strongly discouraged.

Comment: (continued) (c) The upvotes here suggest site members believe it has value, so I don't plan to delete this one. (d) Please accept your answer to effectively mark this as solved, when you are able to do so (i.e. 48 hours after you asked the question). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @SamGibson, if I encounter this situation again, I will not duplicate the answer; instead I will flag instead of vote close. On that note, do you know of an SE meta discussion on how to choose between Arduino SE and EE SE when posting a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the source code, `RH_ASK.cpp`, I found a commented out macro.

```
// RH_ASK on ATtiny8x uses Timer 0 to generate interrupts 8 times per 
// bit interval. Timer 0 is used by Arduino platform for millis()/micros() 
// which is used by delay()
// Uncomment the define RH_ASK_ATTINY_USE_TIMER1 bellow, if you want to use 
// Timer 1 instead of Timer 0 on ATtiny
// Timer 1 is also used by some other libraries, e.g. Servo. Alway check 
// usage of Timer 1 before enabling this.
// Should be moved to header file
//#define RH_ASK_ATTINY_USE_TIMER1
```

In other words, the default behaviour of RadioHead ASK `init()` is to use **Timer 0**, which causes `delay()` (which uses `millis()`/`micro()`) to behave incorrectly.

**To fix:** Tell RadioHead ASK to use **Timer 1**. Because the `RH_ASK_ATTINY_USE_TIMER1` macro is in the source and not the header (for now), you have to modify the actual RadioHead ASK source file, `RH_ASK.cpp`*. Un-comment the line `#define RH_ASK_ATTINY_USE_TIMER1` which will use **Timer 1** instead of **Timer 0**. Re-compile your code, and `delay()` should start working properly again.

* `RH_ASK.cpp` can be found in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead` on Windows, if you installed RadioHead via the Arduino IDE library manager.